# Call asm from c++

Tags: visual-c++, inline-assembly

I want to call define a function in asm file and call this function from a Cpp file/function. Also I have to compile the project on 64-bit platform.

Please help me in doing that as I don't have much idea about assembly code. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[This file](http://sourceforge.net/p/ffdshow-tryout/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/cpuid.asm) is an ASM file from ffdshow that performs some work with CPUID. It's both x64 and x86. YASM is used to assemble it.

What most people do today is not write ASM code but use intrinsic functions. There are intrinsic functions for all SSE/AVX/etc. even for low level ring0 instructions. Intrinsic functions allow the compiler to do extra optimizations and are shared between 32 and 64bit builds.

Answer (score 0):

A code snippet would help, but if you want to place inline assembly within a regular C++ function, you can do that by placing it in an asm block like this:

```
    void myClass::myFunc() {
    // cpp code
    int a = 0;
    // ...

    // asm code
    __asm {
        mov eax, ebx;
        // ...
    };

    // more cpp code
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Inline asm is 32 bit only (Visual Studio). 64bit ASM must be in a separate file.

Comment: Hi Smith,
First of all thanks for your help.
But I don't want to place inline assembly within a regular C++ function as we cannot compile it on x64. We need to separate assembly code in asm/s file for 64-bit